# Install and isolate Linux distro to separate drive from Windows

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, multi-boot

So I want to run a multi boot setup on my desktop. I have 4 drives in total. All except #4 are GPT, NTFS.

1. NVMe (Windows 11)
2. SSD (Files)
3. HDD (Files)
4. SSD Empty with no partitions or data (Target Linux drive)

How can I install a Linux distro so it can't see any of the other drives nor access them?

**Some more info:**
CPU: Ryzen 5 3600
MB: Gigabyte B550M DS3H with **UEFI BIOS**

Comment: "How can I install a Linux distro so it can't see any of the other drives nor access them?" - You would just NOT mount those drives (fstab).  Is that not enough?  If so why?

Comment: "How can I install a Linux distro so it can't see any of the other drives nor access them?"
You can't. And why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I install a Linux distro so it can't see any of the other
> drives nor access them?

Operating systems on a disk can see the disks if they are mounted and available.

So then, I can see two possibilities for you.

(1) Make user Data Folders secure and only permit access to those users who should have access. This is a common Server approach and it is a very workable approach.

(2) Encrypt the partitions and have a Key for access to the partition. Linux users would not have the key.

The difficulty with (2) is loss of the Key or the Key becomes inoperative in some other way. This is more common than you might think. Such an event can render your data inaccessible.

I think some variation around the first method is the best approach for you.

Comment: Encrypting the disks wouldn't necessarily prevent a Linux installation from accessing the drive.  You wouldn't be able to access the data on the drive, but the volume could be mounted, it's content's would just be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

If the other drives are physically connected, your Linux system could be able to mount and read them. However you can encrypt the other drives and prevent your Linux system from making sense of the data on those hard drives or even mounting them.

⚠️ **Do not** use Windows BitLocker to encrypt other drives. If you are using BitLocker make sure you back up the Recovery Key outside of the computer. Because every time something changes in the computer (Example: After booting from another hard drive or after changing RAM, etc.) BitLocker asks for the recovery key NOT the password. So if you have not backed up the recovery key, then you cannot recover your encrypted data.

Actually it doesn't matter what Encryption Software you use. Always remember to back up recovery keys and passwords.